# How to check in profile for unscored percent to gain unsung hero?

Tags: discussion, support, zero-score-badges

The site is giving information that there should be more than 10 unscored accepted answers and 25% of total answers.

Query - 1 - So it means Unscored answer percentage should be less than 25% or it should be >= 25%.

Query 2 - How to check/calculate in profile for unscored percent to gain unsung hero?

Comment: I think the 25% refer only to your answers that got accepted, not _all_ your answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. To qualify, `25%` or more of your accepted answers (excluding those you accepted yourself) must have a score of `0`.
2. Apart from doing it manually, you can use this query: [How Unsung am I? - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66537/how-unsung-am-i)

   Be aware that the results might be up to a month old.

Comment: what is userid in the query

Comment: It's the number in the URL of your profile. Your UserId on Stack Overflow is `1347008`.

Comment: This query is either faulty or the data that it is querying is wrong.  The counts on the returns are all wrong for my user id. Using my id 816602.

Comment: @CDSmith: As I stated in my answer, the results might be up to a month old. From your 19 unscored answers, only the 11 oldest appear in the query. The oldest answer that does **not** appear ([this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10665279)) is 30 days old.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for a quick response. I mean this is a superfluous question in and of itself, more just curiosity. But why would results be up to a month old in the first place?

Comment: I've run the query (super cool, by the way, that you can execute queries towards SO). However, the result is "0". That's wrong (both for the last month **and** all time before that. Has the query passed it's expiration date due to the recent update or am I just being retarded somehow?

Comment: @Chamster: It works with my UserId, but not with yours. I can't know for sure, but this might be related to your suspension.