# How much of an Unsung Hero am I right now?

Tags: discussion, zero-score-badges

Is there a way to find out how far from Tenacious and Unsung Hero I am **at this moment**. (And by that I mean maybe with a few days delay but not weeks or even months). It's not the purpose of the site to serve that information so I won't be surprised if it's not doable but I got to ask.

There are SQL queries that check such things but those work on heavily outdated data.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132359/how-to-check-in-profile-for-unscored-percent-to-gain-unsung-hero?rq=1) is a suggestion to do that manually, but I'm not sure how. Surely, it's not meant that I'm to go and write down my statistics on a piece of Notepad and do some calculations in Excel. Or is it?

Comment: Here is a query that works https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese Ahem... Doesn't that require access to the production DB of StackOverflow? I'm not sure I'm allowed to poke around there... Or am I missing something?

Comment: It includes the time last time it was updated :) nah you dont require any access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the answer [you pointed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132359/how-to-check-in-profile-for-unscored-percent-to-gain-unsung-hero?rq=1) to you can do it manually (annoying) or use the Data.SE query (data can be old). Additionally you can also write an application against [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

If you go the manual route you can use the ninja search options to make things easier  `user:me isaccepted:1`

Comment: OK, by the "annoying" epithet, I conclude that it **is** about actually tracking the stuff yourself. Good info (+1) on the search parameters. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 10):

You can check how close are you to the badge here: [How close am I to unsung hero badge](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/121674/how-close-am-i-to-unsung-hero-badge-including-10-days-requirement) just enter your Stack Overflow ID.