# Block another user from abusing one

Tags: discussion, abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users)

There's a user, a contractor working at our company, who's decided to prove to me that on-line cooperation is not functioning. He's already caused me to be banned for a week and I fear that he'll keep doing stuff to make my life sad.

Is there a way to delete or ban him? Of course, he can register again but it takes a while before he has reputation high enough to start messing with me again.

Even better solution would be to ban him from seeing me and my posts, so he can bother someone else or none at all.

EDIT:

I'm shocked at the negativity. In fact, he did nothing of the kind you're assuming. In fact, he **UPVOTED** my posts so I got canned for inappropriate reputation manipulation.

Comment: A contractor...? Did you consider the obvious?

Comment: Why were you temporarily disabled? He was trolling you and you were not able to decline the bait? Ignore the user and move on with using Stack Overflow normally. If the other user misbehaves, he'll be flagged by the community and handled by the moderators as needed.

Comment: If he is downvoting all of your posts then [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) should help.  If he's posting abusive comments, making abusive edits, etc. then just flag the relevant comments/posts and a mod should handle it.

Comment: *"He's already caused me to be banned for a week"*...that sounds to me like there was a problem with your behaviour or contributions. I don't see how you could have been banned otherwise.

Comment: @Arjan & Bart Well, the only real way that I could imagine anyone other than himself being the cause for his own ban would be a question ban resulting from a lot of downvotes, potentially coming from serial downvoting.  Looking at his reputation tab though, I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @Servy Though a post-ban would not be a week-ban. I would assume that was a moderator giving him a time-out. Though that's only an assumption

Comment: @Bart Yeah, it appears to not be the case here, but it seemed like useful information not worth deleting.

Comment: @Arjan What's the obvious? Not sure what you mean...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Banned for attempted manipulating of reputation (which I didn't do). Please see my edit.

Comment: @Servy Neither. Please see the edit. He's in fact a malicious user, not an idiot... Sadly...

Comment: @Bart Pleae, kindly see the edition I made to my OP. I'm sure you'll see how it could be otherwise. Thank you. Also, there's nothing wrong with my contributions (i hope) since no one has ever complained. You can check me up very easily to see my language and politeness. I feel sad knowing somebody believes otherwise in regard to me.  :)

Comment: If we vote you back to zero, you'd end up gaining reputation -- there you go, trying to manipulate the system again... we won't fall for it!

Comment: @JQAn Not sure we understood eachother. I got downvoted because my formulation wasn't clear and people assumed that I was whining. Now, that I explained the issue, I believe that the circumstances have changed. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Chamster I have read your edit. And my answer (see below) remains the same. Explain the situation to a mod and let that be the end of it. You're 36 years old I see? This should really be a trivial situation which should lead to nothing more than a shrug.

Comment: @Chamster If he is upvoting your posts the system will automatically undo those votes (which has already happened).  If you weren't involved in the reputation abuse then you shouldn't be punished beyond the vote reversals.  If you notice a user intentionally abusing the reputation system you can also report it yourself by flagging a related post.

Comment: @Chamster: I doubt JQAn was being serious there.

Comment: @Chamster The circumstances haven't really changed, no.  The resolution is the same, ignore the problem until it goes away on it's own, or flag for mod attention if that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Bart I strongly feel that we're talking past each other. I couldn't care less about that person's attempts. However, for one week I couldn't ask questions which made my life at work quite miserable. I'd like to avoid such a situation. You seem to believe that I'm looking for a retribution but it's far from true. I'm looking for being left alone by that individual.

Comment: Which doesn't change my answer at all. The same still applies.

Comment: `"You seem to believe that I'm looking for a retribution but it's far from true."`  Well, you did ask for his account to be deleted...  Is there a reason you waited until the ban was over to bring up the issue?  Why not bring your case to the mods during your ban if you felt that you were banned unjustly?

Comment: @Servy Yes, the system does that. It also notifies a moderator about it and he/she bans you for a week... It's the last part that makes me sad...

Comment: At which point you should have flagged for moderator attention stating "Hey, I get the ban. No problem. But the situation is this .... Could you have a look into that?". Job done. And failing that, you could perhaps have emailed the team. But I hardly think that would have been necessary.

Comment: I think you should clarify *why* you actually got banned, a "vote fraud reversal" alone shouldn't warrant a ban. If the system/management thinks you're upvoting your own posts it could lead to a ban (same IP address as your co-worker perhaps, looks suspicious), and if you're not, you should address *that* issue.

Comment: @Chamster The mod *may* ban you if they feel you were complicit, or that both accounts were yours.  You can always state that you were not and than the other person was maliciously trying to implicate you.  Why did you choose to wait until the ban was over to bring it up?

Comment: @Servy Not to argue the issue but: "*...even better solution would be to ban him from seeing me and my posts*". Let's forget it. I was hoping for advise, which I got, sort of. Now I feel like an idiot for opening my mouth. Let's just drop the subject. Sorry.

Comment: @Bart I did that. This far (a week gone) - no reply. I don't think I'll get one. They have a lot of stuff to do. Sorry to bother you. Didn't mean to cause annoyance.

Comment: @Servy Because I couldn't post during my ban. And a message to the person who set the ban I sent directly. No reply there, though.

Comment: As I said, this might take some investigation on their part. It won't be the first time someone claims to have been banned without any wrong doing. And you're not causing annoyance. You're just making much more out of this trivial situation than you should realistically do. Not for us, but for your own good. It's a Q&A, not your life.

Comment: @Bart Good point. It's just that my work got affected. And that **is** my life. Sadly the work is all of it... Couldn't post, couldn't ask. Dark times... Maybe I should start dating again, haha.   :)

Comment: @Arjan What was the obvious thing? Maybe I'm slow but I don't see it... Shouldnät a contractor be **nice and polite** to the clients?! I always am.

Comment: @Chamster Okay...we'll get right on that and fix your contractor for you.

Comment: @Servy No, no, that's not what I meant. I don't want anybody to be fixed, whatever that meant (sounds unpleasant, though). I just want him not to "*prove that collaborative knowledge database like wiki och news is stupid*". That's how it all started. Based on some replies I'm fearing a little that he might be right, hihi.   :)

Comment: By banning him and deleting his account? Do you listen to what you say?

Comment: @Chamster Why would you want him to not prove that?  Why not instead just want to have your questions answered when you have them?  That goal is best served by just ignoring him and leaving him alone, or possibly going to your boss and resolving the issue outside of SO entirely.

Comment: @GEOCHET I've got a dilemma. It's rude not to answer to people (on one hand) but I fear that you're trying to get me agitated (on the other). Not sure if you're kidding or aiming at prolonging the discussion. Sorry if it's offending you but I'll assume it's a troll-like behavior and not feed it. Please accept my apologies if I'm missing your point.

Comment: Guys, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147396/164403) if you want a little more context. @Chamster, as I commented in that question, *not answering questions from that user* strikes me as the way to go. Nothing would probably have happened had you refrained to do so.

Comment: @Servy If I'll talk to my boss, he'd be flying out in warp speed. He's got some conflicts here before. I don't want to cause a human being to become unemployed. I'm not **that** in love with SO. As I wrote, I was mostly hoping to get him banned from seeing **my** stuff.

Comment: @Chamster: What kind of conflicts?

Comment: @Chamster If a contractor I was working with was actively trying to impede my ability to do work, or impede the work of my boss/employee/co-worker I would most certainly want them to be fired.  Not only are they not being helpful, but they are actively being harmful.  Clearly that is not behavior that should be rewarded or even not punished.  If this isn't an isolated incident but in fact is a pattern of behavior then it's all the more reason to want him gone.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I **didn't** replied to anything of him after somebody has pointed out to me that his nick was just like mine only backwards. Creepy, hihi. He'll be back at work on monday and I think he'll start by upvoting me to a ban again.   :(

Comment: "banned from seeing my stuff" ... not going to happen, but you might want to clarify that anyway. @GEOCHET took offence to what was seemingly an outright request to ban him completely I think. Which I can understand.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I'd prefer not to say. It doesn't feel right to "wash his dirty underwear" behind his back. I think he's under a lot of pressure, though. I hope you'll understand that I don't disclose that information.

Comment: @Chamster: That's understandable.

Comment: @Bart Oh, I guess I formulated myself unclearly. 16 hours of coding does that to one's head, hehe. Please accept my apologies. I'd prefer that he said that to me straight. I was suspecting a troll, there, and I never know what to do. Ignoring a person seems so brutally rude, my mom would slap me silly for it. Seriously, she would.

Comment: @Servy I see your point but I would shame to look in the mirror if I haven't tried to get mine (being left alone) and his (trying to prove the point) to work together. I'm afraid that he'll be having hard time finding work if he can't stay here. Don't ask me why.   :)

Comment: @Chamster His trying to prove a point is not the issue here.  He is perfectly within his rights to think that SO is a terrible site.  When he took that opinion to the extent of actively sabotaging your ability to do work he went from the completely acceptable to the completely unacceptable.  I don't know if I would fire someone for that alone, but I'd consider it, and if it was a pattern of behavior I would be considering it very strongly.  In any case, it is not your responsibility to determine if he is fired, it is his bosses. It is (probably) your responsibility to inform him of this issue.

Comment: @Servy You're making an alarmingly good argument. Darn those ethics collisions... I guess you're right. It's in fact my obligation to can him. (I'm sort of his boss, because he reports to me and his pay goes from my budget. And I think that the others don't really pray for his staying with us, so I'm the last line of defense, so to speak. I need to think it through...) Do you know what Arjan meant in the first comment, by the way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok, first off: next time someone tells you they're gonna "prove online cooperation isn't functioning", contact a moderator. It's a lot easier to convince someone of your story when you're telling it *before* bad things happen.

Second: if this starts to happen again, contact a moderator. The user in question hasn't been active since his suspension; if he returns to the same behavior, there's a pretty solid chance the account will be deleted straight away.

Third: if you're making this up because you got caught sockpuppeting, you're wasting your time - just *don't do it anymore*, and you'll be fine.

Comment: That was a **splendid** answer. Since the length of this thread is starting to resemble a list of complaints at my local restaurant, I'll be shutting up, from now on. Thanks to everybody who help (or at least intended to).

Answer (score 15):

The answer to this is very simple really. If he does or says something inappropriate, [flag the offending answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review)/[comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) for moderator attention, perhaps explaining what's going on.

Should he be consistently downvoting or upvoting your contributions, then the system will most likely pick this up and undo it. If not, flag a related question/answer for moderator attention, explaining what you think might have happened.

And that's it. There's nothing more to it.
A moderator will investigate the case (which might take some time) and take appropriate actions if any are necessary.

Whatever you do, don't try to go into full war-mode with a particular user. Use the systems/tools already available and let moderators handle it.

Comment: Of course not. No any scale of war. That would be childish and undignifying. There's enough of that on the net. Arguing on the net is like participating in special olympics. Even if you win, you're still a retard... Can you post a link on how to contact a moderator so I can check you?

Comment: Just flag a post. Even your own. Either an answer/question or comments. Under "It needs moderator attention" for posts or "other" for comments you can enter your own message.